# How to count cells with same background color and value in excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to count cells with the same background color and value?

Comment: not that I am aware of using excel formulas... VBA could do the trick if you are open to using the macro on your workbook.

Comment: Since you have not tagged VBA ... Find Format >> Find All >> Control+A to Select All .. If those cells are not empty you can see the count in the status bar.

Comment: In case of VBA -- [Count the number of cells with a specific cell color using VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/count-cells-number-with-color-using-vba)

Comment: You can use a filter to filter the data by a color in a column, then run `COUNTIF()`?